# Отправить на печать PDF документ с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Доброго времени суток! Стоит довольно интересная задача с которой я бьюсь уже несколько дней.

Нужно из js (а в частности react) отправить документ, который приходит с сервера в запросе в base64, отправить на печать в браузере клиента и вот тут проблема.

Открыть его в соседней вкладке не стоит никакого труда, но после того как он открылся нельзя вызвать функцию .print(), т.к это окно уже не имеет отношения к текущему сайту и браузер режет этот вызов по соображениям совести.

Может кто сталкивался с такой задачей или проблемой? И какие вообще могут быть решения.

P.S. Пробовал еще библиотеку printJS, но не вышло. Может конечно что-то не так сделал :)

Comment: Сервак ваш или полностью сторонний?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму полностью наш

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму нашли ответ?

Comment: @ZhiV, да забыл отписать. Распространенный подход - это создавать js  скрытый фрейм ведущи на страничку с  документом. Внутри фрейма на onload вызывать print() то есть страничка печатает сама себя. Собственно для этого и нужен контроль над страничкой с документом, чтобы там print() можно было написать.

Answer (score 1):

Все уже придумано за вас [print.js](https://printjs.crabbly.com)


`printJS({printable: base64, type: 'pdf', base64: true})`


или как-то так с использование того же printJS (правда не полностью адекватно кроссбраузерно, в IE пойдет на сохранение)

```
getpost('http://fileget/base64.php')
    .done(function(resp) {
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
                byteChars = atob(resp),
                bytes = [],
                i = 0;
            for (; i < byteChars.length; i++)
                bytes[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
            var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(bytes)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            saveAs(blob, 'hello.pdf');
        } else {
            printJS({ printable: resp, type: 'pdf', base64: true });
        }
    })
    .fail(function(x) {
        console.log(x);
    });
```

или это попробуйте:

```
function createPDF(pdfInBase64) {
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
        byteChars = atob(pdfInBase64),
        bytes = [],
        i = 0;

    for (; i < byteChars.length; i++)
        bytes[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);

    var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(bytes)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    // создаём object URL из Blob
    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
    else {
        var newWin = window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank', 'width=500,height=300,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes');
        newWin.focus();
        newWin.print(); //чтобы эта строка сработала страница должна быть в сети, т.е. НЕ локально.
        URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
    }
}
```